# The target deployment path '...' does not match the POM's expected path prefix

Tags: maven, jenkins, artifactory, jenkins-pipeline

I am trying to upload a `pom.xml` file to a Maven repository hosted on an Artifactory server. The `<project>` section of the `pom.xml` looks like this:

```
<groupId>com.x.y.z</groupId>
<artifactId>common</artifactId>
<version>2.3.0-RELEASE</version>
<packaging>jar</packaging>
```

I am using the Artifactory plugin for Jenkins in a Pipeline script and here is the `uploadSpec`

```js
{
    "files": [
        {
            "pattern": "target/common-2.3.0-RELEASE.jar",
            "target": "REPOSITORY/com/x/y/z/common/2.3.0-RELEASE/common-2.3.0-RELEASE.jar"
        },
        {
            "pattern": "pom.xml",
            "target": "REPOSITORY/com/x/y/z/common/2.3.0-RELEASE/common-2.3.0-RELEASE.pom"
         }
     ]
 }
```

When I now try to upload the artifact, I'm getting the following error message:

```
java.io.IOException: Failed to deploy file. 
  Status code: 409 
  Response message: Artifactory returned the following errors: 
    The target deployment path 'com/x/y/z/common/2.3.0-RELEASE/common-2.3.0-RELEASE.pom' 
    does not match the POM's expected path prefix 'com/x/y/z/common/2.2.7'. 
    Please verify your POM content for correctness and make sure the source path is a valid Maven repository root path. Status code: 409
```

Before I upload the `RELEASE`, I upload a `SNAPSHOT` which (in this case) had the version 2.2.7-SNAPSHOT. After that I bump the version to `2.3.0`, re-build the project with `mvn clean install` and then start another upload to Artifactory. Somehow Artifactory still seems to expect the "old" version, when I try to upload the new version.

**Edit**

When I upload the file with `curl`, everything works as expected:

```
curl -user:password-T pom.xml \
"http://DOMAIN/artifactory/REPOSITORY/com/x/y/z/common/2.3.0-RELEASE/common-2.3.0-RELEASE.pom"
```

So it seems like this is related to the Jenkins Artifactory Plugin.

Comment: reminder to myself: here's the issue tracker https://www.jfrog.com/jira/projects/HAP/issues/HAP-910?filter=allissues

Answer (score 5, accepted):

You upload your pom file to an incorrect location. You use

```
REPOSITORY/com/x/y/z/common-2.3.0-RELEASE.pom
```

as a path, when the path should be

```
REPOSITORY/com/x/y/z/common/2.3.0-RELEASE/common-2.3.0-RELEASE.pom
```

Note version-named directory that is missing.

The good news are you don't even need to bother with it. When you use our `Artifactory.newMavenBuild` for Maven builds, we'll take care of the correct deployment. See [the example](https://github.com/jfrog/project-examples/blob/master/jenkins-examples/pipeline-examples/scripted-examples/maven-example/Jenkinsfile).

Comment: hi @JBaruch - thanks a lot for the quick reply... the path in the `target` was a typo in the post - I had the path you suggested and screwed it in my post... so that's not the issue... I will try the `newMavenBuild` as suggested by you next week :) happy easter!

Answer (score 1):

Can you try the below code in pipeline script?

```js
{
    "pattern": "pom.xml",
    "target": "REPOSITORY/com/x/y/z/common/2.3.0-RELEASE/common-2.3.0-RELEASE.pom"
 }
```

or if it doesn't work you can utilize maven deploy in pipeline script using

```
 def mvnHome = tool mvnName
 sh "$mvnHome/bin/mvn deploy -deploy-file -Durl=file:///C:/m2-repo \                                                                               
                                            -DrepositoryId=some.id \                                                       
                                  -Dfile=path-to-your-artifact-jar \                                                                                
                                  -DpomFile=path-to-your-pom.xml
```

Comment: sorry - had a typo in my post... that path was as you suggested but I screwed it in my post... I am now using `curl` and it works for the moment. `mvn deploy` has some other implications which I wanted to avoid - but thanks for the tip!